# How to output compact log level in serilog using code based configuration

Tags: c#, serilog

Code based configuration and file based configuration seem to yield different log level compactness on output when using serilog.

I get [2020-05-15T13:09:36 Information] when using code configuration where as i get [2020-05-15T13:09:37 INF] using config file configuration.

I would appreciate if anyone can tell me how to get "INF" instead of "INFORMATION" with code based configuration.

**Code configuration:**

```
   return new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Verbose,
                    outputTemplate:
                    "[{Timestamp:s} {Level:Level:w3}] {Component} {PollCount} {RequestId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}")
                .WriteTo.File(
                    $"{Path.GetTempPath()}\\Logs\\agent.log",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose, 
                    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:s} {Level:Level:w3}] {Component} {PollCount} {RequestId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}"
                    )

                .CreateLogger()
                .ForContext<T>();
```

**appsettings.json configuration:**

```
  "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:s} {Level:Level:u3}] {Component} {PollCount} {RequestId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}"
              }
            },
```

Comment: Your output template in code is not the same as your output template in configuration.

Comment: Duplicating `Level` in the `{Level:Level:u3}` placeholder is incorrect - the format should just be `u3` here, e.g. `{Level:u3}` - HTH

Answer (score 0):

By default full names are used for logging events. To override using output Template.
valid values for Level are  **u (for uppercase) or w (lowercase) and a number of characters**. The level names are abbreviated, Information is shortened to "INF". I think due to invalid value it is displaying default text

So Level:u3 will output INF

Level:w3 will output inf

Official link for serilog with info on levels [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#output-templates)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.

I think it's time i got my self glasses or start diffing everything.. U=I can't believe i could not distinguish u from w.

Comment: @user2021262 It happens sometimes :). Glad could be of help